# Is this solution to this exercise correct?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to solve this exercise using 2 IN operator, but I have a doubt: does this query return the TeacherID to the his/her corresponding courseID (without using a join)? Or I need to put a join in the in the WHERE of the outest query (the first one where I have "FROM COURSE C")?
[image]
Here's my code:

```
SELECT C.TCODE, C.CCODE
FROM COURSE C
WHERE C.TCODE NOT IN(
SELECT TCODE
FROM COURSE
WHERE TOPIC <> 'DATABASE'
)
AND C.CCODE IN (
SELECT C1.CCODE
FROM LECTURE L1, COURSE C1
WHERE L1.CCODE = C1.CCODE
GROUP BY CCODE, TCODE
HAVING AVG(AttendingStudent#) = (
SELECT MAX(C3.MEDIE)
FROM (
SELECT C2.TCODE, C2.CCODE, AVG(AttendingStudent#)
FROM LECTURE L2, COURSE C2
WHERE L2.CCODE = C2.CCODE
GROUP BY C2.TCODE, C2.CCODE
) C3
WHERE C3.TCODE = C1.TCODE and C3.CCode = C1.CCode
) 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about providing some sample data

Comment: @Pugzly I don't know how to create a database, that's the problem

Comment: did my suggestion help? Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you supplied no data and expected output I made some up and changed the column names to something more meaningful to myself. Feel free to retrofit to your specific needs. This solution works with Oracle.

As to test, you can create an account with Oracle live SQL. Its a free site that allows users to access an Oracle database. I would strongly suggest doing so in order to test your code you put forward

Since this appears to be a homework assignment and you don't have access to a database as an incentive I left the value of the highest average attendance out of the solution for you to put in. If you are unsure how to do it, post another question.

Note on stackoverflow to post formatted code for other people to read you can encapsulate the starting and ending pieces of code with 3 consecutive ~~~

Lastly you should never post screenshots as people are usually hesitant to help if they have to type in your table structures and data.

```
create table dept(  
  department_id     number(2),  
  department_name      varchar2(30),    
  constraint dept_pk primary key (department_id));
/

INSERT INTO dept(department_id, department_name)
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'PROGRAMMING' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DESIGN'  FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE teachers (
   teacher_id  number(*,0),
  first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  department_id NUMBER(2),
constraint department_id_fk foreign key (department_id) references dept (department_id),
constraint teacher_pk primary key (teacher_id));

INSERT INTO teachers (
teacher_id, first_name, last_name,
department_id)
SELECT 1, 'Ann', 'Abbott', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 'Boop', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Charles', 'Caputo', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 'Downing', 3 FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE course (
   course_id  number(*,0),
   course_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  enrolled_students number(*,0) NOT NULL,
  teacher_id NUMBER(2),
  topic VARCHAR2(20),
constraint teacher_id_fk foreign key (teacher_id) references teachers (teacher_id),
constraint course_pk primary key (course_id));


INSERT INTO course (
course_id, course_name, enrolled_students, teacher_id, topic)
SELECT 1, 'C programming', 35, 1, 
'Programming' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'C programming', 28, 2, 
'Programming' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'Design', 50, 4, 
'Databases'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'SQL', 50, 3, 
'Databases'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 'SQL', 50, 1, 
'Databases'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 'C programming', 45, 3, 
'Design'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 'PLSQL', 50, 4, 
'Databases'  FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE lectures (
   lecture_id  number,
   room_id  number,
   start_date DATE,
   end_date DATE,
   course_id  number,
   attending_students number,
   constraint course_id_fk foreign key (course_id) references course (course_id),
   constraint lectures_pk primary key (lecture_id));


INSERT INTO lectures (lecture_id, room_id, start_date, end_date,  course_id, attending_students)
SELECT 1, 1, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 09:00:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 10:45:00',
3, 49 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 09:00:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 10:45:00',
3,48 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 1, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 09:00:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 10:45:00',
3,47 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 2, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 11:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 12:55:00',
4, 39 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 2, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 11:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 12:55:00',
4, 38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 2, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 11:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 12:55:00',
4, 37 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 7,3, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 13:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-20 15:55:00',
5, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 8,3, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 13:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-21 15:55:00',
5, 22 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 9,3, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 13:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 15:55:00',
5, 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 10,4, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 17:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 18:55:00',
7, 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 11,4, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 17:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 18:55:00',
7, 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 12,4, 
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 17:30:00',
TIMESTAMP '2022-06-22 18:55:00',
7, 16 FROM DUAL; 


SELECT
   t.teacher_id,
   t.first_name,
   t.last_name,
   c.course_id,
   c.course_name
 FROM teachers t join course c on c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
WHERE c.topic = 'Databases'
AND   c.course_id in (                               
        select course_id                          
        from   lectures                              
        group  by course_id                          
        order  by avg(attending_students) desc      
        fetch  first row with ties                   
      )                                             
ORDER BY  t.teacher_id;

TEACHER_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   COURSE_ID   COURSE_NAME
4   Debra   Downing 3   Design
```